# Refreshing DataGridView bindings to a list when a row is deleted

Tags: winforms, datagridview, data-binding

I have a WinForm app with multiple DataGridViews bound to SortableBindingLists.

Under some circumstances, I need to programmatically delete an item from the list that grid is bound to.

I can't seem to get the DGV to recognize that it's data has changed, or, specifically, that it has fewer rows. I'm calling dataGridView1.Invalidate(), and it's repainting the grid, but it tries to repaint as many rows as their were before, and throws a series of exceptions that "Index  does not exist", one exception for each column.

Here's a simplified code sample that exhibits the problem: (just a WinForm with a DGV and a button.)

```
    private List<Employee> list;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list = new List<Employee>();
        for (int ix = 0; ix < 3; ix++)
        {
            list.Add(ObjectMother.GetEmployee(ix+1));
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
    }

    private void cmdDeleteARow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list.Remove(list[0]);
        dataGridView1.Invalidate();

    }
```

In ASP.NET, when using a GridView control, there's a "DataBind()" method you can call to force it to refresh it's data. There does not seem to be any such thing in WinForms, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order for a `DataGridView` to pick up on changes to its `DataSource`, the source should implement [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.aspx). `List<T>` doesn't, so it doesn't broadcast its changes, and the  `DataGridView` doesn't know it needs to be updated.

An easy fix in this case is to put a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) between the list and the `DataGridView`, and then call `Remove()` on it instead:

```
private List<Employee> list;
private BindingSource bindingSource;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list = new List<Employee>();
    for (int ix = 0; ix < 3; ix++)
    {
        list.Add(ObjectMother.GetEmployee(ix+1));
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
    bindingSource.DataSource = list;
}

private void cmdDeleteARow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindingSoruce.Remove(list[0]); // or, RemoveAt(0)

    // Probably not necessary:
    // dataGridView1.Invalidate();
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) instead of `List<T>`, or create your own list class that implements `IBindingList`.

Comment: This is super old, but it's near the top of Google so I'll throw a few things in here. Switching to a BindingList 100% works perfect. Secondly, something that caught me out, if you use the bindingsource way, if you run add/removes on the original list, you won't see changes reflected on the DataGridView. You need to run the add/removes on the bindingsource.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since I'm not getting any useful responses, I'm going to go ahead and use the kludge I've come up with.

If you use reflection to go into the DataGridView.DataSource property, you'll see that the binding methods are only called if the DataSource changes.  Note that a change to the contents of the DataSource (e.g, adding, changing, or deleting a list element) are not recognized as a change to the DataSource.  In order to force the data binding methods to be called, what I have done successfully is to reassign the DataSource to some other object, then assign it back to the list.  Seems incredibly kludgy, and a monumental waste of CPU cycles, but it appears to work.  So the code becomes:

```
    private void cmdDeleteARow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list.Remove(list[0]);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<Employee>();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
        dataGridView1.Invalidate();
    }
```

If anyone has any better ideas (and I'm sure there have to be some out there), please let me know.

Comment: i was getting same error as your's and my scenario was lil' bit same thing i.e reading data of a datadridview in a for-loop and doin' some operation on each row and at last deleting the current row...so what i did is created a delegate function for deleting it coz i'm using background work thread... it work'd for... r u using ne background thread

Comment: Andrew Watt posted a very good answer. Yours is neither an answer nor good. Put a tick on Andrew's post please.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dataGridView1.Refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael, but it gives the same result.  I tried replacing the Invalidate call with Refresh, and also tried leaving the Invalidate in and adding Refresh before, and then after. The all still throw the same exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using Validate() method of the container object and it works smoothly when it comes to synchronizing data grid view and bound data table.

An example in Visual C++ could be given as:

// Assuming dgv has already been created in the code as a Data Grid View object

SplitContainer^ dgvContainer = dynamic_cast(dgv->Parent->Parent);
dgvContainer ->Validate();

Hope it helps.